# add AJAX on custom python browser

Tags: python, ajax, webkit, pygtk

I'm making a custom browser in python but my AJAX calls don't work. (work on firefox and others browsers.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import gtk
import webkit

DEFAULT_URL = '/var/www/profile.html' # Change this as you Wish
class SimpleBrowser: # needs GTK, Python, Webkit-GTK
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        self.window.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER_ALWAYS)
        self.window.connect('delete_event', self.close_application)
        self.window.set_default_size(1366, 743)
        self.window.set_position(0)
        vbox = gtk.VBox(spacing=0)
        vbox.set_border_width(0)
        self.txt_url = gtk.Entry()
        self.txt_url.connect('activate', self._txt_url_activate)
        self.scrolled_window = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        self.webview = webkit.WebView()
        self.scrolled_window.add(self.webview)
        vbox.pack_start(self.scrolled_window, fill=True, expand=True)
        self.window.add(vbox)
    def _txt_url_activate(self, entry):
        self._load(entry.get_text())
    def _load(self, url):
        self.webview.open(url)
    def open(self, url):
        self.txt_url.set_text(url)
        self.window.set_title('007WallPaper')
        self._load(url)
    def show(self):
        self.window.show_all()
        #self.window.fullscreen()
    def close_application(self, widget, event, data=None):
        gtk.main_quit()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        url = sys.argv[1]
    else:
        url = DEFAULT_URL
    gtk.gdk.threads_init()  
    browser = SimpleBrowser()
    browser.open(url)
    browser.show()
    gtk.main()
```

How can I "import" AJAX functionality into it ??
Maybe i can use pyqt ? Not sure how i can do that but i really need it.

Comment: it works well for me using this URL to test `DEFAULT_URL = 'http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first' `. Can you show us the ajax calls code you are testing?

Comment: a simple `$.ajax({type: "GET",url: "test.php",success: function(data){alert("success");},error: function(data){alert("Error");}});` to a file "test.php" with just "hello" as text, popup error and crash for me.

Comment: in `url:"test.php"`, try add the full url : `http://127.0.0.1:80/test.php` or whatever you have.